# prolog, exshell, known predicate?

Tags: prolog, expert-system

I am trying to implement an expert system with ExShell under Gprolog using the code I obtained from https://www.cs.unm.edu/~luger/ai-final/code/PROLOG.exshell_full.html. However, I keep on getting the error:

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,known/2),solve/0)
```

The only thing I needed to change was on lines 334-335:

```
write_premise(not Premise) :-
    !, write('     '), write(not),write(' '), write(Premise),nl.
```

to

```
write_premise(\+ Premise) :-
    !, write('     '), write(\+),write(' '), write(Premise),nl.
```

I am using their example for automotive diagnostics to test it. I am not sure if there is something I can do to fix this, or if someone knows where I can grab some source code for ExShell that will work with gprolog.

Comment: Just in case you are wondering why so many `write/1` calls are needed to do such a simple job: they *aren't*! Consider using `format/2` instead. For example: `format("    \\+ ~w\n", [Premise])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the `know/2` predicate as a dynamic predicate using the directive:

```
:- dynamic(know/2).
```

Comment: This did solve the issue. As a side note, I did install swi-prolog and tested this there as well, the same issue occurs and this fixes it as well. Additionally, the predicate `retractall` needed to be changed as well to work in both gprolog and swi-prolog. After which the automotive demo worked flawlessly.